# AngularJS - HTML Table handling of click events

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat-start=... data-ng-click="contactGroup.expanded = !contactGroup.expanded">
         <td class="myColumn" data-ng-click=...>
```

when a row is clicked than the row expands and additional information is shown to this row - this works fine.
In this row there is also a column (**myColumn**) which can be clicked.
If this column is clicked than first the row expands and than the proper click event is handled. Is there a way to prevent the expandation of the row when the column **myColumn** is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is happening because of event bubbling and to stop it `event.stopPropogation()` can be used.

While clicking the column bind a method; and use `$event` to prevent default

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat-start=... data-ng-click="contactGroup.expanded = !contactGroup.expanded">
         <td class="myColumn" data-ng-click="toggleColumn($event)">
```

And in Controller:

```
$scope.toggleColumn = function(e){
    e.stopPropogation(); //This would prevent event bubbling from td to tr
    e.preventDefault(); //This will prevent default action like link load on click of hyperlink
    //toggle functionality
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the row click event in column and remove from the row.

Please check the bellow.

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat-start=... data-ng-click="">
         <td class="myColumn" data-ng-click="contactGroup.expanded = !contactGroup.expanded; <columnClickEventHandl>">
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<table>
  <tr data-ng-repeat-start=... 
      ng-click="!contactGroup.expanded && contactGroup.expanded = !contactGroup.expanded">
     <td class="myColumn" ng-click=...>
```

note, that assignment in the row's *ng-click*'s expression will be executed only when `contactGroup.expanded` is `false`